# What happens if the gate voltage exceeds the drain voltage in a source follower with an active load?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, source-follower

What happens if the gate voltage exceeds the drain voltage in a source follower with an active load?

Here is the circuit:

[image]

If we try to increase input voltage even more than Vdd, what happens then? The current source is constant. We may guess that source and drain exchange their position and now we have two currents which want to pass in the opposite directions. What does it mean?

Notice that we are analysing large-signal performance.

Comment: The source voltage cannot exceed the drain. Vgs can continue to increase until the spec is exceeded and the device fails.

Comment: Note: I read the schematic as the load being a current sink.